# Why is an FRN price equal to par on every reset date?

Tags: fixed-income, interest-rates, bond, floating-rate

In the book "The money markets handbook" by Moorad Choudhry, it says that "on the coupon reset date an FRN will be priced precisely at par".

Why is this? Would it not discount the future curve and hence the potential return from the Euribor+spread (therefore be priced under par if the two rates are positive and viceversa)?

Comment: You receive Euribor+spread on the bond and you discount using Euribor+spread so you get par. Changes in Euribor are reset on the reset date and hence both the received and the discount value are the same. However, spread is set at origination and does not change at interest reset date. If spreads widen or tighten then the bond will be below or above par, so I am not sure I understand/agree with the author. Also FYI most FRNs have an interest rate floor and these often do not equal par at interest reset date!

Comment: This is only true if the discount margin and the quoted margin are the same.

Comment: Ok. 

But your logic, Trevor, is theoretical. Because in practice, this seldom happens. Am I right in thinking that this does not happen because of expectations/market demand/supply dynamics?

Comment: I second @TrevorHansen: In a credit-risk-free world, the coupon will be such that it outweighs the discounting. But with credit risk, it is quite unlikely that the FRN will be at par at any reset date, simply due to the fact that the issuer will most likely not have a flat credit spread.

Comment: The spread at which you discount is the discount margin. This changes over time. If the issuer is looking more credit risky it increases and vice-versa. The fixed spread paid on the coupon leg is the quoted margin. If they are the same on a coupon date then the FRN is worth par.

Comment: @Snowmate no it is in practice not in theory that the spread can change? Here are some ISINS that show that the credit spread drives the price and that FRN are not priced precisely at par at interest reset date: USU9273ACS25, XS1944384350 & XS1550988643. I think that during the corona crisis spread widening was driving and that there were few (none?) corporate bonds at par on the interest reset date at the end of Q1 2020.

Comment: I am agreeing with you @TrevorHansen. I was directing my reply to Snowmate, not you.

Comment: @Dom my bad! Apologies.

Comment: No worries. The way these comments are not threaded is confusing.

Comment: @snowmate If you do Python you can check this out. https://github.com/domokane/FinancePy/blob/master/notebooks/products/bonds/FINBONDFRN_CitigroupExample.ipynb